# Python using Tkinter (Raspberry Pi running Debian).

Tags: python, tkinter

To use Tkinter to open a dialog box I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
from Tkinkter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import asksavesfinename

root = Tk().withdraw()
f = asksaveaskfilename()
```

This works just fine if I run the program under Idle.

However, if I run it, as root, from the LXTerminal, it fails with the exception “Client is not authorized to connect to Server…..”

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: do you get this same error for any GUI program run under the same circumstances (logged in as root in the LXTerminal), or does it only happen with Tkinter applications?

Comment: this code has errors. Check if this is what you actually run

Comment: I just noticed something, if I run the program as:

Comment: My whole comment: I just noticed something: If I run the program, from the terminal, as: python filechooser.py it brings up the dialog box OK.  If I run the program as sudo python filechooser.py it fails with the exception.  I have not seen this type of problem running as root with other programs from the terminal.  This is a part of a larger program that must be run as root as it has GPIO commands.  Joaquin, can you tell me what my errors are.  The post agrees with the code I run

Comment: Apparently I have a problem with X windows allowing me to add a graphic but not root.  I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: You're importing `Tkinkter` which I've never heard of.  Also, you're importing `asksavesfinename` (which AFAIK doesn't exist in `tkFileDialog`), and you're referencing `asksaveaskfilename`, which also doesn't exist in `tkFileDialog`.  Both of those, I would think, should be `asksaveasfilename`.  Perhaps you are actually programming in `Pykthon`? ;)